# Options for running controller method from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, controller

Ruby on Rails 3.2: I made a table, a model and controller. I want to run the "new" method in my controller.
Off the top of my head I can think of a form to run the method. What other options are there to run controller methods?

In particular I would like to run the "new" method when viewing certain view files. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can add the new action to a link, use a form, and call the action using Ajax. Any other alternative other than those will violate MVC.

Comment: Do you know where any AJAX with rails tutorials are that do not use forms?

Comment: You don't necessarily need a form to do Ajax.
Just sprinkle a little bit of Jquery and listen to events on your UI and then trigger the ajax call. There are lots of documentation on how to achieve this online, doesn't need to be Rails specific. Please accept my response, it it helped you. Thanks